# How to stop the ship before falling into whirlpool?

Tags: unity, c#

I am programming a game in Unity with C#

1. I have a ship which I needs to move towards the whirlpool (target).
2. The ship has to be stopped before entering the whirlpool.

I need advice as to how to implement my `distToWhirlpool` and `distToStopPoint`

Here is the assignment I'm trying to solve:

> In this task, control the movement of the hero ship around the
>   lake and stop within a defined distance of a whirlpool.
>
> **Task Outline**
>
> Control of the ship’s movement is achieved by commanding the activation of forward and
>   rotational thrusters and/or providing a target point given the information available on the
>   environment. Control is required to ensure that the hero ship can move safely around the
>   map without colliding with objects that would damage or destroy it. To demonstrate control
>   you must accelerate your ship to a prescribed speed and maintain this speed for about 2
>   seconds.
>   As the hero ship moves, the interface will give it its position in the lake and its distance
>   from the lake’s centre. To complete the task the hero ship must move to a whirlpool and
>   stop within a defined distance from it without being sucked in to the whirlpool.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour {

    public struct Velocity2 // Structure of velocity
    {
        public float forward;   // Forward velocity of object in m/s
        public float right;     // Velocity to the right of object in m/s
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct Position2 // Structure of a position
    {
        public float north;     // meters north from centre of lake
        public float east;      // Meters east from centre of lake
    }


    public struct HeroStatus    // Structure of information on the Hero's status
    {
        public Velocity2 velocity;      // Velocity of the Hero in m/s - - not changeable
        public Position2 position;      // Position of the Hero - not changeable
        public float angleCW;           // Orientation of Hero in degrees ClockWise from North - not changeable
        public float shield;            // Shield energy available, range 0 - 1 - not changeable
        public float Hull;              // Hull integrity, range 0 - 1 - not changeable
        public bool shieldActive;       // True when the shield is on - not changeable
        public float distFromCentre;    // Hero distance from the centre of the lake - can be used to avoid lake edges - not changeable
        public float maxForwardSpeed;   // This reports the maximum forward speed of the Hero in m/s - not changeable
        public float maxRotationSpeed;  // This reports the maximum rotational speed of the Hero in degrees/sec - not changeable
        public bool task;               // True if Hero is in Task Mode, else Hero is in Game Mode - not changeable
        public int level;               // In Task mode this is the task number, in game mode this is the level number - not changeable
        public int maxLives;            // The maximum lives available  - not changeable
        public int livesLeft;           // The number of lives left in the game. In Tasks it is the number of tries left for the task. - not changeable
        public float taskTimeMax;       // The amount of time a task has to complete the task - not changeable
        public float taskTimeLeft;      // During tasks this is the time remaining to complete the task. - not changeable
        public float stopDistToWhirlpool;   //Dist to stop from Whirlpool in Task 1 - not changeable
        public float whirlpoolDiameter; // Diameter of a whirlpool
        public bool inMenu;             // True when the Game or Task is in a menu  - not changeable
        public bool useAI;              // True when AI mode is active
        public bool useForwardThrust;   // True when forwardThrust and not forwardSpeed is use for forward/reverse motion 
        public float maxForwardThrust;  // Maximum forward thrust available
        public bool useRotateThrust;   // True when rotateThrust and not forwardSpeed is use for forward/reverse motion 
        public float maxRotateThrust;  // Maximum rotate thrust available
    }

    public HeroStatus heroStatus;       // Hero's status - updated every frame - not changeable

    public Position2[] drones;          // Array of all drones - updated every frame
    public Position2[] whirlpools;      // Array of all Whirlpools - updated every frame
    public Position2[] shieldPowerups;  // Array of all Shield power ups - updated every frame
    public Position2[] hullPowerups;    // Array of all Hull Power ups - updated every frame

    public bool useTarget = true;   // If true, the target variable is used as a position to move toward,
                                    // If False, only forwardSpeed/Thrust and rotationSpeed/Thrust is used to move the Hero

    public Position2 target;        // This sets the position the Hero should move toward - Uses 'forwardSpeed/Thrust' and 'rotationSpeed/Thrust' parameters to move

    public float forwardSpeed = 0;  // This sets the desired forward speed of the Hero in m/s - Used when useThrust is false
    public float rotationSpeed = 0; // This sets the desired rotational speed of the Hero in Degrees/sec
    public float forwardThrust = 0; // Thrust used to drive Hero- Used when useThrust is True
    public float rotateThrust = 0;  // Thrust used to rotate Hero- Used when useThrust is True

    public bool turnOnShield;   // When set to true turns on the Hero's shield - If the Shield is out of energy it will not turn on

    public bool logData = false;    // Set to true to start a data log file and reset to false to close the file.
    public string logDataString = "";// Once the data log file is open, the contents of this string will be write to the data log file.
                                     // When the data file is first opened, this string will be writen to it as the first line of date. 
                                     // So Use it to set column heading and put commas between each heading.
                                     // Also put commas bewteen data to create a Comma Seperated Variable (CSV) file for excel.
    public bool resetDataRunTime = false;   // Set this to true to reset the datalogging run time that is reported in the data log to zero.
                                            // It will be reset to false automatically.
    public string debugString = ""; // The contents of this string will be writen to the screen. Toggle it on and off with the I key.

    // **************************************Do Not Modify the variables above ************************************************************

    //***************************************Place your variables below********************************************************************
    public float thrustScale = 0.001f;
    public float stopDist = 55f;
    public float velScale = 4.2f;

    // Used to initialise at the start of a Game Level or Task
    public void StartTaskOrLevel()  // This is called at the start of each Task or game level
    {
        forwardThrust = 0f; // Initialise motion to zero 
        rotationSpeed = 0f;
    }


    // Used to update Hero during a task or Game Level.
    public void TaskOrLevelUpdate() // This is called 50 times per second during a Task or game level but not when a menu is displayed.
    {
        if (heroStatus.task)
        {                   // Do Tasks
            switch (heroStatus.level)
            {
                case 1:
                    task1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    task2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
            }
        } else
        {                   // Do Game

        }
    }

    // Used to close anything at the end of a Game Level or Task
    public void EndTaskOrLevel()  // This is called at the end of each Task or game level
    {

    }


    public void task1()
    {
        float deltaNorth, deltaEast, distToWhirlpool, distToStopPoint;
        float desiredVel;

        deltaNorth = whirlpools[0].north - heroStatus.position.north;
        deltaEast = whirlpools[0].east - heroStatus.position.east;
        distToWhirlpool = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(deltaNorth, 2) + Mathf.Pow(deltaEast, 2));
        distToStopPoint = distToWhirlpool - heroStatus.stopDistToWhirlpool;

        target = whirlpools[0];
        useTarget = true;

        desiredVel = distToStopPoint * velScale;
        if (distToStopPoint < stopDist)
        {
            forwardThrust = heroStatus.maxForwardThrust * -desiredVel * thrustScale;
        }
        else
        {
            forwardThrust = heroStatus.maxForwardThrust;
        }
        rotationSpeed = heroStatus.maxRotationSpeed;
    }

    public void task2()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit rude to ask us to do your homework/assignment without showing any effort. Please consider [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/should-we-treat-questions-about-assignment-in-a-different-way/2659#2659) in such situations.

Comment: As a side note: your HeroStatus struct should really be a class. Read the Microsoft docs for more info on when to use structs or not. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by "north and east" as coordinates, can you please give an example?

But I can help you with some pseudocode:
So part one would be to find the actual goal of your ship, which is "before the whirlpool". You can count it like this

```
vector3 direction = whirlpool.position - ship.position; //gives you direction
direction = direction - direction.normalize() * distanceToWhirlPool;
```

distanceToWhirlPool is how far from it you want the ship to stop.

then, (probably in the ship's update function) you would do:

```
this.rotation = Lerp.(this.rotation, rotationToWhirlpool); //rotating towards the whirlpool, you can use other ways
this.move(this.forward * shipSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Do you have any questions? Is anything not clear?

Comment: In this task your agent must control the movement of the hero ship around the
lake and stop within a defined distance of a whirlpool.